# Can I get the first day of the week based on locale data?

Tags: go, time, locale

Different countries begin a work week on different days (Sunday vs. Monday, etc.)

Go has the [text/language](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language) package, and the [time](https://pkg.go.dev/time?tab=doc) package has support for locations, but I can't find anything in the core libraries that mention the start of the week.

Is there a way to get the first day of the week, given a locale?

Comment: Standard lib: no. 3rd party: off-topic. It's easier to just list the few locales you wish to support.

Comment: @icza what do you mean by "3rd party: off-topic"?

Comment: Asking for 3rd party libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: perhaps a more accurate phrasing would be "open source"

Comment: It makes no difference, the wording is like _"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."_

Comment: I understand what you mean. Seems arbitrary to enforce if an open source library is the only solution to an answer

Comment: It's not arbitrary to say that questions that lead to opinionated answers are off-topic. Whether the opinion is "open-source" or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Well it seems like there are some opinions [involved in this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/5A6VAJmcTko).

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that there is no consensus and therefore no standardization about what the first day of the week should be. It is not locked even per country, but more per person. Hard to write a lib on that. I would just pick a first day and maybe let the user decide which day he wants.

Comment: @RickyA Perhaps, though unicode do have CLDR which is a base for many
http://cldr.unicode.org

Comment: If you really want to understand why this is policy, search on meta. There are more discussions about this than you can shake a stick at. If you just want to complain or argue, though, then I can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no std library that can do this

Comment: Off-topic: there's an OS library that can: https://github.com/noamt/go-cldr